# Is there a way to access the Trailer headers in a chunked-enconded response in .Net 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, httpwebrequest, http-headers, chunked-encoding

Using HttpWebRequest/Response, and the Trailer headers in the chunked-encoded response are being thrown away (I've actually stepped through the .Net 4.0 reference source to see where it calls RemoveTrailers after the final chunk).  Is there any way to retrieve those headers?  Also, does anyone know why this behavior is in place to begin with?

In case anyone asks, no, I can't ensure that the trailer headers are moved to the rest of the headers.  This is simply the data stream format I have to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is any way to do that. As to why it is like this, when this feature was first being implemented, there was no known HTTP server that sent headers in chunked response trailers.

What kind of server is this? Is this a custom server that is doing this?

If you absolutely care about this, you can find a feature request at the MS connect website (http://connect.microsoft.com).

Comment: Yes, it's a system of custom storage servers.  Even if no one was using it at the time, it seems easy enough to implement just because it's part of the RFC, but I'll save that soapbox for another time  :)  Thanks!

Comment: Does the server support HTTP/1.0 ? If so you can downgrade your request to HTTP/1.0 and then the server should not send chunked response. BTW what is so special about this server? What headers is it putting in the chunked trailer?

Comment: No, we need to use HTTP/1.1.  It's a storage cluster node.  I don't have an exhaustive list of the headers that can go into the Trailer for this server, but I believe they rely (at least in part) on the data that was sent prior.